# How to display the books of specific users stored in google books using google books api??

Tags: android, xmlhttprequest, google-books, jsonparser

I am trying to make an android app for tracking the list of books read by users. I successfully completed the search for books using keywords with google books API. **Now I need to display the books added by users to their google books bookshelf**.
I tried the following https code

> https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/mylibrary/bookshelves/7/volumes?key="+key;

I could not find anything from searching the internet. Please help me with this.

Here is my github repo https://github.com/Sibinjoseph111/Bucherwurm